# Titanium View.toImage() and base64 encode not always decoding properly

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I Have a simple android only app using `myView.toImage()`

This is returning a blob, as expected,great!

I can then encode this blob to base64,and a test decode in the app by loading the decoded string into an `ImageView` renders the image perfectly.

But when decoding this string in php the base64 string has 2 problems:
Firstly the string length is not always a multiple of 4 i.e., no padding has been added, and secondly when padding is added manually the image is always blank.

Using the same code on a button object however works perfectly, this only appears to happen when using the `toImage()` method on a Ti.View object

**Working code (produces a good base64 string)**

```
myButton.toImage(toImageComplete);

function toImageComplete(blob){
Ti.API.info("To image complete" + blob);

var sigBase64 = Ti.Utils.base64encode(blob); 
Ti.API.info(sigBase64);
}
```

**Non working code (produces a bad base64 string), note the only change is the object that is calling toImage is now an instance of Ti.UI.View, instead of Ti.UI.Button**

```
myView.toImage(toImageComplete);

function toImageComplete(blob){
Ti.API.info("To image complete" + blob);

var sigBase64 = Ti.Utils.base64encode(blob); 
Ti.API.info(sigBase64);
}
```

Appcelerator Studio 4.6
SDK 5.3.0GA
Compiling to Android tablet and Genymotion simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so 3 days of trying this, 3 days of frustration and I finally have a solution. If it helps anybody avoid wasting the the time I have wasted:

This was actually working all along, but I was using the output of a         `Ti.API.info()` to view the resulting base64 string. It appears that `Ti.API.info()` truncates long strings. When the base64 string was saved to the Database and retrieved all worked as expected.

Moral of this story...Dont use `Ti.API.info()` to log long strings, they will be truncated

Comment: Sometimes, after encoding a ImageView, the encoded string gets a break line after 76 charsets: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-9111.

I'm using a regex to remove those: myEncodedImage.toString().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,'')